# How can I access my spark SQL-query on aws-glue snowflake

Tags: apache-spark-sql, snowflake-schema

When I run my awsGlue job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BANK_OBJECTID FROM {0}""".format(WAREHOUSE.HUB_GIS_ASSET_MAP)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/testglue", line 31, in <module> bike= """SELECT DISTINCT BANK_OBJECTID FROM {0}""".format(WAREHOUSE.HUB_GIS_ASSET_MAP) NameError: name 'WAREHOUSE' is not defined
```